# Amazon like auto-complete from two tables with elements in common

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I have two Tables in `database`, `Books` and `Films`. I have some common elements. What I need is an auto complete just like that of `amazon` `auto-complete`. Suppose the common element is Harry potter. So when I type Harry potter the auto complete box should come as **Harry potter in Books , Harry potter in Films** just the same as of `amazon`.

I have referred some tutorial and I have got something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#amzQry").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function (req, res) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete',
                cache: true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: {
                    'search-alias': 'aps',
                        'client': 'amazon-search-ui',
                        'mkt': '1',
                        'q': req.term
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    return false;
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    res(data[1]);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

<input id="amzQry">
```

It is working some what in its own way,. Not as my expected way. My json as follows:

```
[
    "Books",
    [
        "Harry potter",
        "King Lear",
        "Alchemist",
        ....
    ],
    "Films",
    [
        "Harry potter",
        "Avatar",
        "Terminator",
        ......
    ]
]
```

I had provided this json inside :

```
url: 'myjson'
```

But un luckily it is not working. Please guide me to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a json like this format:

```
[
        {"label":"Harry potter", "actor":"Books"},
        {"label":"Harry potter", "actor":"Films"},
        {"label":"King Lear", "actor":"Books"},
        {"label":"Alchemist", "actor":"Books"},
        {"label":"Avatar", "actor":"Films"},
        {"label":"Terminator", "actor":"Films"},
];
```

And then tried the jquery autocomplete:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
var data = [
            {"label":"Harry potter", "actor":"Books"},
            {"label":"Harry potter", "actor":"Films"},
            {"label":"King Lear", "actor":"Books"},
            {"label":"Alchemist", "actor":"Books"},
            {"label":"Avatar", "actor":"Films"},
            {"label":"Terminator", "actor":"Films"},
    ];
$( "#search" ).autocomplete(
    {
        source:data,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.label + " / " + ui.item.actor );
            return false;
        }
    }).data( "uiAutocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a><strong>" + item.label + "</strong> in " + item.actor + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };      

});

<input id="search">
```

Check this link to refer: [Reference](http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/jquery-autocomplete-json-example.html)
It will work. I got the expected Result!! Cheers!!